# Excel cannot open a file "filename.xlsx" because file format is not valid error in IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to open excel 2007 from jsp (i.e) if user clicks on generate report button dialog box with open/save button will display(it's an ordinary download dialog box). if user clicks on open button warning msg saying "**Excel cannot open the file Report.xlsx because file format or extension is not valid**". I'm getting this error only in IE8 & MS 2007 combination not in IE6 & MS 2007 combination.

Most of the google websites talking about MIME type. Even i changed the MIME type to MS 2007 excel as below in my code still getting the warning msg.

I searched google completely there is no server side solution. In most websites they asked to add registry in client side machine but i want server side fix.

This is the code...

response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" "Report.xlsx");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma","public");

Comment: Are you by chance using Apache-POI to write to Excel?